# Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"

Tags: node.js, database, express, handlebars.js

I want to make a site through Express, but after some lines that I copied from YouTube, it began to give this error. I don’t know how to fix it, read other answers to this error, but it didn’t help. I hope you can help me

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const salatRoutes = require('./routes/routerSalat')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs'
})
app.engine('salat', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'salat')
app.set('views', 'views')


app.use(salatRoutes)

async function start() {
    try{
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://salat:123123123@cluster0.ysp2i.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        })
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('Сервер запущен.')
        })
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

routerSalat.js

```
const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Can you show files and directories structure of your application?